# Does $A^2B^2=I$ imply $AB=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and $A^2B^2=I$, does it mean that $AB=I$?
If that is true i would like to see the proof to it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't change the question so significantly after it has been answered. You are welcome to just post a new question instead.

Answer (score 9):

If $A=[-1]$ and $B=[1]$, then $A^2B^2=[1]$ but $AB=[-1]\neq [1]$.

Comment: and if B= A transpose?

Comment: This example can be generalized by taking $A$ to be any idempotent matrix and $B$ to be the identity (wikipedia has examples of more complicated idempotent matrices).

Comment: sorry but i cant understand that answer so much, let me just write the full question:
prove or contradict:
if A^2 is an orthogonal matrix so A is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @ptrsinclair idempotent matrices are not invertible. Perhaps you meant that the matrix should square to the identity?

Comment: @AvihayTsarfaty That significantly changes the question. Maybe you should edit the original post.

Comment: @MattSamuel You are absolutely correct, that is what I meant.